# How to open Oracle APEX tree link in new window conditionally

Tags: oracle-apex

I've an Oracle APEX tree which displays different functions. My query has a column for function type. If function type is FORM, I want to open link in new window. Otherwise link opens in the same window.

Currently I'm using javascript:window.open("&LINK.","_blank") in Tree attributes to open link in new window. This applies to all functions. Please advise.

Additionally I'm looking same functionality for Card link as well.

Thanks
Kishore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### APEX tree

1) Add a column TARGET to the tree's query like this

```
case when function_type = 'FORM' then '_blank' else '_self' end as target
```

2) Change the tree attributes to:

```
javascript:window.open("&LINK.","&TARGET.")
```

### Cards report

The Cards report template as shipped does not support the target attribute, because it defines the link like this:

```
<a href="#CARD_LINK#" class="t-Card-wrap">
```

You could make a copy of it and modify that to (for example):

```
<a href="#CARD_LINK#" class="t-Card-wrap" target="#TARGET#">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using javascript:window.open("&LINK.","&TARGET.") opens all functions in new window. Non-form based function shows the url as href="javascript:window.open("https://hostname/RF.jsp?function_id=127","")"

Comment: See amended reply - added '_self'

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. How do I bring the same logic to Cards region?